# Помогите найти способ реализовать блок

Tags: html, css, html5, css3

Объясните, как реализовать блок из дивов.

Как сделать так, чтобы картинки были слева на расстоянии друг от друга? Как на скриншоте. Чтобы шрифт справа, ровно начинался с верха каждой картинки и снизу подпись.

Я начал делать через списки - получился треш. Начал делать через дивы. Все картинки в див - и что-то не задалось.

Сейчас есть идея сделать главный див. В нем на каждую картинку по диву и справа на текст по диву, так-как по мне, ими проще манипулировать. Итого шесть дивов в одном блоке.

Это адекватный выход? Это похоже на табличную верстку.

Какой должен быть принцип построения в такого типа блоках?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Этот вариант я уже думал делать, но не получается сделать дистанцию между картинками по вертикали в диве с картинками... уже начинал думать делать каждую картинку в диве..

Answer (score 1):

```css
*{
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

.b-test {
  max-width: 600px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  font: 14px/1.4 "Segoe UI", sans-serif;
}

.b-test-inner {
  margin: 25px auto;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  display: table;
  width: 100%;
  background: #fff;
}

.b-test-item {
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: top;
  padding: 15px;
}
.b-test-item:nth-of-type(1){
  padding-left: 0;
}

.b-test-item > h3 {
  font-weight: 700;
  font-size: 18px;
  margin-top: 10px;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 480px) {
  .b-test-inner,
  .b-test-item {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="b-test">
  <div class="b-test-inner">
    <div class="b-test-item">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/100x100" alt="" />
    </div>
    <div class="b-test-item">
      <p>Объясните, можно словами, как можно реализовать этот блок из дивов.. Как сделать так чтобы картинки были слева на растоянии друг от друга как на картинке, и чтобы шрифт справа ровно начинался с верха каждой картинки и снизу подпись.</p>
      <h3>Title</h3>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="b-test-inner">
    <div class="b-test-item">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/100x100" alt="" />
    </div>
    <div class="b-test-item">
      <p>Объясните, можно словами, как можно реализовать этот блок из дивов.. Как сделать так чтобы картинки были слева на растоянии друг от друга как на картинке, и чтобы шрифт справа ровно начинался с верха каждой картинки и снизу подпись.</p>
      <h3>Title</h3>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="b-test-inner">
    <div class="b-test-item">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/100x100" alt="" />
    </div>
    <div class="b-test-item">
      <p>Объясните, можно словами, как можно реализовать этот блок из дивов.. Как сделать так чтобы картинки были слева на растоянии друг от друга как на картинке, и чтобы шрифт справа ровно начинался с верха каждой картинки и снизу подпись.</p>
      <h3>Title</h3>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: спасибо, вообще четко! ))